# Corrupted objects when using Spring Batch with Embedded datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I got strange results using Spring Batch in conjuction with embedded storages like H2.

Here is my case:

My project is just regular Spring Boot microservice. Domain layer has an entity *Model* class with transient *List* field. This field is backed by *byte array* field, which is in turn not transient and supposed to be stored. I use *@PrePersist* and 
*@PostLoad* to serialize and deserialize list. After model is loaded I clear array so it doesn't take memory.

The service has two controllers: *ModelController* and *AnalyzeController*. Each of them executes Spring Batch job. First job creates Model and stores it into db. Second job pull model from db and use it for calculating.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Model")
@Slf4j
public class Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 36)
    private String id;

    @Transient
    private List<Cluster<ItemPoints>> clusters;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BYTEA")
    private byte[] serializedClusters;

    //region Serialization / Deserialization 
    @PrePersist
    public void serializeClusters() {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
            oos.writeObject(clusters);
            serializedClusters = out.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(SERIALIZATION_ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }   

    @PostLoad
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void deserializeClusters() {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedClusters);
             ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in)) {
            clusters = (List<Cluster<TimeSeriesItemPoints>>) is.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error(SERIALIZATION_ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
        }

        // clear serialized data as it is no more needed
        serializedClusters = new byte[]{};
    }
    //endregion
}
```

Repository layer is provided by Spring (CrudRepository)

If I try to execute AnalyzeController after ModelController for the first time it works as expected, but further calls to repository return Models with empty array (and List won't be deserialized).

This happens only with embedded database and single DataSource (same for batch processing and models).

If I use two different DataSource, it works correctly. If I use an external database it works correctly even with a single DataSource (PostgreSQL for example). Also it works OK with single datasource and no Spring Batch.

Configuration for single datasource case:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default")
public class DefaultDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: So far from your question, nothing related here to spring batch. Why do you think this is spring batch's issue?

Comment: Probably, because it works OK without batch jobs.